# Android camera application crashes on closing

Tags: android

I have written a camera application. It has an infinite loop created inside "onCreate" that takes a picture every second:

```
    Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            camera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    };
    mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable,1000);
```

After that it runs a classifier based on caffe. However when I exit the application at some point I always get an error saying:

```
"App has been stopped"
```

At the same time I get the following error message in `Android Monitor`:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
             Process: com.myUsername.myAppName, PID: 25490
             java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(android.hardware.Camera$ShutterCallback, android.hardware.Camera$PictureCallback, android.hardware.Camera$PictureCallback)' on a null object reference
                 at com.myUsername.myAppName.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:178)
                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:702)
```

Does anyone have an idea how to avoid this error? Do I need to call some special functions when finishing the app that end the infinite loop or explicitly shut down the camera which runs in preview mode?

Comment: are you using custom camera ?

Comment: null pointer exception mean you have not initialized camera object. Kindly check

Comment: well the app works fine. So i guess its not a problem of initialization.   I'm not sure about the "custom camera" question. I'm using `public static Camera camera = null; camera.startPreview(); private Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to stop a loop after closing an activity. For example:

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private volatile boolean isStopped = false;

    @Override public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        this.isStopped = false;
    }

    @Override public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        this.isStopped = true;
    }

    @Override public void onResume() {
        Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(!isStopped) {
                    camera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
                    mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                }
            }
        };
        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable,1000);
    }

}
```

Comment: you mean probably `private volatile boolean isStopped ...`.  What about the `super.onStart/onStop()` methods do I need to remove them as in your example above? Unfortunately this method also doesn't seem to restart the infinite loop when reopening the app... May I need to fully shutdown the app instead of pushing it in the background

Comment: It's working now. Apparantly it's ok to call `super.onStart/onStop()`. In `protected void onStop()` I'm calling `finish();` which ends the app completely. Thanks all for your help

Comment: Yeah, sorry about thos missing supers and boolean. I tried to write this code without IDE which made me forget about some stuff.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using custom camera then you need to release camera before leaving the activity. so call camera.release() in onDestroy() method.

Comment: camera is already released. That doesn't seem to be the problem here. It's rather the infinite loop

Comment: remove callback from handler then        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);

Answer (score 0):

you need to stop the runnable(probably in your onBackPressed() method) before the app closes, since the runnable is executing takePicture after the camera is null.

Comment: That sounds promissing. Could you evolve on that? My `mRunnable` is created inside `onCreate` so I guess it cannot be seen in some other method. I assume `onBackPressed` is called when hitting some home button?

Comment: @mcExchange look at my answer. You  don't really need to keep track of thread/runnable - it can take care of itself. You can use flag to tell your loop to stop looping. Also, using onBackPress doesn't cover some use cases (home button, another app hijacking foreground etc.)

Comment: also as a general tip , you should use asyncTask

Answer (score 0):

You can check null-able like this:

```
 Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(camera!=null)
              camera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    };
    mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable,1000);
```

Comment: Ok that helps to avoid the error message mentioned above, but when I reopen the app, the loop unfortunately doesn't restart... any idea how to restart it? (I also don't want the app to keep running in background for battery saving so I included `mHandler.postDelayed` in the if statement...

Comment: You can refer following for your scenario  [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734074/how-do-i-make-a-simple-timer-in-java-with-a-button-click-to-start-stop-the-timer/33734950#33734950)